# Objective C - Messaging objects within objects

Tags: objective-c, oop, messaging

I have a query about messaging objects which have been instantiated within a different object.
Specifically I want to keep my 'gamestate' object separate from my 'GLview Object' and be able to call methods belonging to each object from within the other.
What is the best way of achieving this?

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of achieving this.

The most obvious is that your superclasses may be defined with properties referencing their properties (sub-objects, as you're describing). Eg, [[gamestate subObject] doSomething], where 'subObject' is a synthesized property pointing to the object you want to message.

If you want looser coupling, consider using a pattern of delegation or registering for notifications.

Your nestled objects may define a delegate protocol, calling it's delegate methods at appropriate times. If another object conforms to the protocol and is assigned as the delegate, it will receive the messages.

Finally, objects can register for notifications. Object A can post notifications (e.g., 'something happened'), and Object B can register to for notifications (e.g., perform method X when you're notified 'something happened').

Comment: Thanks isaac, got it working. I created property references to allow the instance variables to be accessed outside the object. I obtained a copy of the glView pointer and passed this to my rendering object. Registering for notifications looks promising as well, will be checking that out! Thanks again.

Comment: I am curious, is passing pointers the proper way to send messages to objects outside the current instance? I have come across a problem relating to the touch input which only seems to work when I keep the touchesbegan inside the GLview.